# how to change webelement to text (browser = webdriver.Chrome)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

The goal of my python code is to find the prices of the land on the webpage, and later on also the land area. The code I currently have outputs .webelement in a list, and I want to change it to text (e.g. $131,000).

Current output:

```
[]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="51532a6317af2be5bfd34c6406d59028", element="65e6939c-3077-4c7a-8dfa-eaa109a0fc0f")>]
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="51532a6317af2be5bfd34c6406d59028", element="0221ed59-744e-4e1e-9fc8-5db77a04a2eb")>]
```

Below is the current python code I am using:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/land/?page=1'

r = requests.get(url)

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

data= []
price = []

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://www.realestate.com.kh/buy/land/?page=1')

follow_loop = range(0, 14)
for x in follow_loop:
    xpath = '//*[@id="__next"]/main/div[2]/div[1]/div['
    xpath += str(x)
    xpath += ']/article/div[2]/div[1]/div'
    price.append(driver.find_elements_by_xpath(xpath))

for p in price:
    print(p)
driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for p in price:
    print(p.text)
```

just call text

if it doesn't bring everything then,

use p.get_attribute("textContent")